# Blurred text in HTML

Tags: html, css

I am developing a blog. You can see it [here](http://www.apptec.net/) if you want. While creating the "AppTec Team" area in the sidebar, I am having trouble. I want to create the text area as it is right now but I don't understand why is it unclear? If you see the area you would find that the font looks blurred. I understand that I am using deprecated tags but I do not have another choice as where whould I put its css then?
The code I pasted in text widget is,

```
<p 
style="background-color:#8E1E03; 
text-align:center;
font-size: 16px;
font-family:Times New Roman;
color:white;">
<i>Fraz Awan</i></p>
<p     
style="
background-color:#171717;
text-align:center;
font-size: 16px;
font-family:Times New Roman;
color:white;"
> IT Guy </p>
```

I would be very thankful if someone could help me remove the blur in the text. Thanks

Comment: There isn't enough info here to answer the question.  Namely, i don't even see the alleged blur in the linked-to page, and the HTML pasted here doesn't replicate the issue.  Voting to close as too localized.

Comment: You don't see it because its fixed. Whats so localized in it?

Comment: The fact that there's no longer a way to answer the question (or to verify that any answer works), because the problem is gone and can't be reproduced with the info given here.  "Too localized" means "This question is unlikely to ever help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, **a specific moment in time**, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet."

Comment: Well, the code is still there to help people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `text-shadow` in `.sidebar` class which is causing it to look blurred.

Also, if you want the text-shadow for you heading change the CSS to `.sidebar h4{text-shadow:1px 1px white;}` and remove the text-shadow from .sidebar class.